# Mysql: ORDER BY a field randomly if a field has a value

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I want to create a query like this

> SELECT id, name, type, image FROM table ORDER BY type ASC, image.....

Pick up all type A rows first randomly, then list all type B rows randomly and all type C rows randomly. Within a same type, check if the row has image or not, then list rows with image randomly above rows without image.  
The table has several thousand rows.
Any one has a good solution? Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: you have already written the query.  You just have to update the query based on what kind of values you store in image column.  What other solution you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY type ASC, CASE WHEN image IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE RAND() END ASC
```